# why binomial test is considered "nonparametric"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, nonparametric, definition

why binomial test is considered "nonparametric" ? After all it is used to test against an hypotetical parameter p in a binomial distribution, so IT IS about a parameter !

edit:I don't remember exactly where I read it, but I read it quite often. With a quick search on google I found some occurrence of it - I don't know anyway if there is a consensum on it:

1)"Nonparametric Methods Based on a Single Sample: The Binomial
Test"
from Nonparametric Statistical Techniques Trent D. Buskirk, Lisa M. Willoughby, and Terry T. Tomazic
https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199934898.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199934898-e-006

2) Lucerne University:
"The binomial test is a non-parametric statistical procedure"
https://www.empirical-methods.hslu.ch/decisiontree/differences/proportions-and-frequencies/binomial-test/

3) University of Sydney:
http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/jchan/r/tes15_2_sol.pdf

4)definition in italian Wikipedia (as of 2 March 2020): "Il test binomiale è un test non parametrico" https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_binomiale

5) in SPSS the binomial test is under the menu " Analyze > Nonparametric test > Binomial"

Comment: Who considers it to be nonparametric? Can you provide a reference / quote that claims this?

Comment: "Parametric" does not refer to the parameter being tested (or even the fact there is a parameter to test): it refers to the *underlying probability model* for the *data.*

Comment: @whuber could you expand your explanation please? if I am doing a binomial test I am assuming that the data is following an underlying binomial distribution, that has a parameter p. I am missing your point.

Comment: A [binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) is far more general than that.  Thus, while *you* might very well be conducting a parametric test in *your* application, there are many nonparametric applications, too.  For instance, you might want to test that an experimental measurement is equally likely to be positive and non-positive. Classifying a set of independent observations into positive and non-positive groups leads to a binomial test *without making any distributional assumptions whatsoever about the measurements.*

Comment: +1 @whuber "For instance, you might want to test that an experimental measurement is equally likely to be positive and non-positive." As in the [sign-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test), where such a measure is a difference in two measures which have identical, if unspecified, distributions under the null hypothesis (e.g., between pre-post, or between matched observations, etc.).

Comment: @whuber's comment about "nonparametric" referring to the probability model of the underlying data is an important nuance. In fact, the sign test, rank sum test, sign-rank test, Dunn's test, etc. *all* are based on parameterized models (i.e., the distribution of signed differences, distribution of rank sums in two groups, signed differences in ranks, summed ranks for $k$ groups, etc.… and this is true for both exact and approximate tests). However, *none* of these nonparametric tests assume a parametric model *of the data* which are being signed, ranked, etc.

Comment: @whuber objection: there not exist in nature any data that is truly generated by a parametric probability distribution (only exception maybe:radioactivity). When we talk about an "underlying probability model" we talk about the modelization we are sticking to it. Whatever the data generator process, without making any distributional assumption on it, in the exact moment in which I am doing a binomial test I am making the assumption that I am viewing it under the perspective of a binomial process -  otherwise it would not make any sense to test it so !

Comment: You seem to confuse the assumptions about the *data* with what those assumptions imply about your *test statistic.*  As @Alexis has tried to point out, statistical tests are possible only because we can deduce specific distributions for the statistics under the null hypothesis. If, then, we were to insist (as you seem to do) that implies such tests are "parametric," then there would be no such thing as a non-parametric test and the distinction would be useless.

Comment: @whuber I'm not confusing data with statistics. E.g. why Z-test is parametric and binomial not? In Z-test we test the sample average, that is a statistic whose distribution can be approximated by a Gaussian (regardless of the distribution of data), and we test the likelihood of obtaining that statistic in an interval defined by the supposed mean of the Gaussian. In Binomial test we test the "number of occurrences" that is a statistic whose distribution is binomial (regardless of the distribution of data) and we test the likelihood of obtaining that statistic in an interval defined by param P

Comment: @MicheleMas Reread my comment about the sign test: there is *zero* parameterization of the underlying data distributions.

Comment: @Alexis ok then in Sign Test we test the statistic W against a binomial with P=0.5 . Assuming that null hypothesis H0 is true, then W follows that binomial. In all cases we assume nothing about underlying data distribution, so we consider it "nonparametric". I get that. But then, why we consider Z-test as parametric, where we are assuming nothing about the underlying data distribution (but we assume gaussian distribution for sample average, like we assumed binomial distribution for W in sign test) ?

Comment: We *do* assume the distribution of differences in sample proportions (which are a kind of sample mean) take *approximately* the z distribution under the null (an approximation with improves with sample size). Likewise, for *t* test we assume that the distribution of *sample means* takes the *t* distribution for normally-distributed data. Note that the former assumes binomialy-distributed data, and the latter assumes normally-distributed data: exactly the kinds of assumptions we *aren't* making for nonparametric tests.

Comment: @Alexis thanks, i think I understand, I was not considering t-test (or z-test) assumptions of normality of underlying data ! (that because my univ professor told us to use t-test and z-test for sample mean testing, disregarding the distribution of underlying data, just because "the sample mean anyway will tend to a normal because of CLT", and now I feel as I always did wrong stuff! ). Meanwhile, binomial test doesn't make any assumption about underlying data (only on the statistic "number of occurrencies"), so it's not parametric. Right ?

Comment: @Alexis Hello, I want to ask - do you consider one-sample score test for proportion and one-sample Wald test for proportion as parametric tests? These tests have the same assumption as binomial test - that all $X_i$s have Bernoulli distribution $\mathrm{Bern}(p)$ and independent. If we consider them as parametric tests then why we consider binomial test as nonparametric?